# Hibernate One-To-One relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, one-to-one

I see many turoials and articles about subject, but i can't understand one thing.
For a example: i have "User" table with fields "id", "name" and i have "UserBanned" table with fields "userid" and "reason".
UserBanned.userid - it is link (foreign key) on field User.id.

So, models in hiberante looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicInsert
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "user_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_generator", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
    protected Integer id;

    @Column
    protected Integer name;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected UserBanned userBanned;
```

And UserBanned model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userbanned")
@DynamicInsert
public class UserBanned{

    @Id
    @Column(name="userid", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
    protected Integer userid;

    @Column
    protected String reason;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    protected User user;
```

And it works. I can create new user and banned user with this code:

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    UserBanned userBanned = new UserBanned ();
    userBanned.setReason(reason);

    user.setUserBanned(userBanned );
    userBanned.setUser(user);

    clientService.store(user);
```

But, when i try to do gson.toJson(client) i got stackoverflow error - because Gson can't handle circular references in the serialized data. But my mind cant understand why i have to set User in UserBanned?! Why i can not just have model User?

My question: how i can organize such relationship (One-To-One with foreign key) like User (there are not only UserBanned, but and UserVIP and etc entities) in hibernate?

Comment: What is `gson`? `google-gson`s Gson instance?

Comment: You can always leverage `Gson` not to follow circular references.

Comment: contexnt not in gson, but in dependency UserBanned form User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `UserBanned` to have reference to `User`, you could make the `UserBanned` embeddable and embed it in `User`.

```
@Embeddable
public class UserBanned{
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicInsert
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "user_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_generator", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
    protected Integer id;

    @Column
    protected Integer name;

    @Embedded
    protected UserBanned userBanned;
```

If you want the `UserBanned` to be in separate database-table and the table should contain reference to the `user`-table, I don't think you can avoid having the `User` in `UserBanned`, otherwise Hibernate won't know which `User` the `UserBanned`refers to.

If you want just to get rid of the line `userBanned.setUser(user);`, you could set the `User` to `UserBanned` in `Users` `setUserBanned(userBanned );`-method.

```
public void setUserBanned(UserBanned userBanned) {
    this.userBanned = userBanned;
    userBanned.user(this);
}
```

And then excluding the field from serialization for example in way suggested in [Ilyas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059395/2492495).

Comment: User, UserBanned, UserVIP, UserStars - it is all separated tables. In this case your answer is right?

Comment: I see.. But it is a pitty. Main reason it is that i can not make one entity with cascade updates two tables.. that's root of the my question-problem. Thnx! Marked.

Comment: One more question please: There are no any other structure too get work these models? User, UserBanned, UserVIP as all separated tables with one same foreign key userid (User.id - primary key)? Only my way? With model user in each model (UserBanned and etc) with foreign key? It this right way or there are some else?

Answer (score 2):

You should exclude one of cycled references (`User::userBanned` or `UserBanned::user`) from serialization and deserialization by `Gson`.
You can read about it in [gson-documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Add some annotation

```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target({ElementType.FIELD})
  public @interface Exlude 
  {
  }
```

Create [ExclusionStrategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html)

```
public class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy 
{
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) 
    {
      return false;
    }

    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) 
    {
      return f.getAnnotation(Exlude.class) != null;
    }
}
```

Create `Gson` instance with `GsonBuilder`

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new MyExclusionStrategy())
        .create();
```

Annotate `UserBanned::user` with `@Exclude` annotation

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@Exclude
protected User user;
```

Comment: i've marked prev answer like answer because it is answer on my first question about dependency User in UserBanned. But your answer helps me too to get some exp in hibernate and in common things in it. Thank you!

Comment: i found one more solution for gson stackoverflow exception: new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE, Modifier.STATIC) - that means fields with concrete modificators gson will ignore.

Comment: But you cann't make the field in `Entity` `static`

Comment: but i can make the field private - and it's field wont be aggregate by gson

Comment: @dikkini this is bad solution

Comment: Thx. Any way i used your answer in my project, and second solution i've seen in other project.